# Query all the employees under a single employee

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have an Employees table.
I am using Oracle database.

```
 Employees Table
 - Employee_id
 - first_name
 - last_name
 - manager_id
 - email_id
```

How can I query all the employees under another employee ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "under another employee"? And could you provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statement for your table please

Comment: Do you mean "directly under" or "under at any level"??

Comment: Hi El Ronnoco, I want to query the employees under an employee at all the levels.

Comment: I'm not sure about in oracle, I have done this in SQL Server and you will either need to use a recursive or iterative function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has a `CONNECT BY` syntax...

```
    SELECT *
      FROM employees
START WITH employee_id = 123
CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id
```